# Is there a LINQ equivalent method?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I know LINQ has a [`SequenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx) method. This method makes sure each item value in each collection matches, in the same order.

What I'm looking for is a more "Equivalent" type of functionality. Just that both sequences contain the same items, not necessarily in the same order.

For example, nUnit has `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()` and `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()` that do what I'm explaining.

I know that I can do this either by:

1. Ordering the lists ahead of time and using `SequenceEquals`
2. Using `Intersect`, then seeing if the intersection is equal to the original sequence.

Example:

```
var source = new[] {5, 6, 7};
source.Intersect(new[] {5, 7, 6}).Count() == source.Length;
```

Comment: There is a mistake in the example of answer. You need to compare it with both counts otherwise your function would return 'true' when source is a subset of target. I.e. source {5,6} and target {5,7,6}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would create an extension method that does the intersect and then compares the counts.

Comment: You get the answer for giving me the idea to compare the counts, so it made it nice and compact, thanks!  Looks like this: var source = new[] {5, 6, 7};  source.Intersect(new[] {5, 7, 6}).Count() == source.Length;

Comment: @CubanX: Note that if the source contains any duplicates, then even `source.SetEquals(source)` will return false.

Comment: @Jon Good point, I might have to throw a distinct in there to ensure that won't happen.

Answer (score 11):

You could build a set and then use [`HashSet<T>.SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx). It's not strictly within LINQ, but it plays nicely with it :)

Of course, you could easily write your own extension method to extend this. Something like this:

```
public static bool SetEquals<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> other)
{
    HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>(source);
    return hashSet.SetEquals(other); // Doesn't recurse! Calls HashSet.SetEquals
}
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, this ignores the number of times elements occur, as well as the ordering - so `{ 1, 2 }` would be "set equal" to `{ 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1 }`. If that's not what you want, it'll get a little more complicated.

Comment: so 1,2 would "equal" 1,1,1,2,2,2?

Comment: @spender: For *set* equality, that's correct. The set of elements in each collection is the same. It's worth highlighting though - will edit.

Comment: Jon, sometimes in methods like this, I can't decide whether to write it as you have it or to do something like `HashSet<T> hashSet = source as HashSet<T> ?? new HashSet<T>(source);` *potentially* saving the cost of constructing a new `HashSet<T>`. Do you have an opinion on that?

Comment: This worked really well, code looked like this which is pretty compact: new HashSet<int>(new[] {5, 6, 7}).SetEquals(new[] {5, 7, 6})

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way:

```
public static bool SetEquivalent<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> aSet,
    IEnumerable<T> anotherSet)
{
    var diffA = aSet.Except(anotherSet).Count();
    var diffB = anotherSet.Except(aSet).Count();
    return diffA == diffB && diffA == 0;
}
```